# Having trouble optimizing simple method

Tags: c#, performance

I successfully implemented this paper (just for my own research) http://eprints.uwe.ac.uk/15260/ But I am running in to a performance issue when following  a particular implementation from the author. To make the story simple and short. I have a class Cell each Cell is stored in a multidimensional array and represents a scalar field. The Cell class has a method to determine if it contains a point or not, this containment test is what is causing big performance issues on my code.

For clarification, in the Cell class I have a method named BoundingBox (not shown here)  which computes the 4 vertices of a square to determine the area for containment. This is how each cell knows if it contains a particle/agent or not. in the Contains method, the m_domainX.Min… etc, holds the min and max coordinates of the containment area. I am also calling BoundingBox  only once; I am only invoking it inside the constructor of the class. But the Containment method is computed every update frame.

I am usually using an [,] array of 150X150 and about 4,000 particles/agents. Basically the larger the array, the lower the performance

I have tried to parallelise the Method but I don't get any performance boost.

For illustration here are some images of the simulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgZ8B.jpg)

```
   // This method belons to the Cell<T> class, and will be used every update frame
    public void Contains(List<PhysarumAgent> particles)
    {
        int ptsCount = 0;

        foreach (var particle in particles)
        {
            if (particle.ForewordSensorB.X >= m_domainX.Min &&
                particle.ForewordSensorB.X <= m_domainX.Max &&
                particle.ForewordSensorB.Y >= m_domainY.Min &&
                particle.ForewordSensorB.Y <= m_domainY.Max)
            {
                ptsCount++;
            }
        }


 m_numAgentsInCell = ptsCount;
            if (ptsCount > 1) m_occupied = true;
            else m_occupied = false;
    }

    // This method belongs to another class. It iterates over the scalar field and calls 
    // the Contains() method for every cell in the field. Computed every update frame.
    private static void ComputeField(SharpField2D<double> scalarField,
        List<PhysarumAgent> PhysarumAgentPopulation)
    {
        ParallelOptions paraOpts = new ParallelOptions();
        paraOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

        Parallel.For(0, scalarField.Columns, paraOpts, i =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, scalarField.Rows, paraOpts, j =>
            {
                scalarField.Field[i, j].Contains(PhysarumAgentPopulation);
            });
        });
    }
```

It would be great to have any pointers, since I am not sure why this simple method is causing so many problems.

Comment: If you have working code that you're looking for peer review to get help optimizing, [codereview.se] was created for just that purpose. This site is for code that *isn't* working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KenWhite and @itsme86, the code isn't working performance-wise. That's the whole point of the `performance` tag on SO.

Comment: @Nicholas It's important to show the performance numbers for different array sizes. Also you should mention the CLR version and the processor you're using, and confirm that you've compiled the code with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @RufusL ...lol... the method is working

Comment: *Working* means *doing what it was intended to do*. *Not performing well enough* is not the same as *not working*, and you just commented *lol... the method is working*. [codereview.se] was established just for the sort of question you're asking. Rather than arguing, you should learn to accept constructive advice and learn how the site works.

Comment: This is basically a brute force implementation.  There are lots of things you can do.  One thing you could do is use octrees, they are well documented and relatively easy to implement.

Comment: @ Rufus L I missed some code at the end of the method, hence your confusion. But I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

1. You have too many comparisons. With 150x150 cells and 4000 particles, you have to test 90M times for cell versus particle.

If your cells form a regular grid, you don't need to run any tests at all. Instead, iterate over particles, for every particle calculate cell index, i.e. divide coordinates by cell size, call Math.Floor, cast to int. If you need to calculate per-cell points counter, or aggregate particles in some other way per cell, write that aggregation code in a way that allows to store the state being aggregated in every cell, and update it incrementally. You probably need to iterate across cells initialize, and then after processing all particles, but that only need to be done per cell, not per (cell, particle) pair like your current comparisons.

2. Also, you probably have too many random RAM accesses. If both cell and particles are classes and not structures, while iterating over array of them you're doing random pointer chase every iteration, if your data set is large enough, that's a cache miss every single time. For this reason, sometimes it makes sense to switch from classes to structures. Unlike reference types, array or list of structures is kept in a continuous RAM addresses, i.e. much faster to iterate.